# Include javascript (or css) as inline in HEAD with Typoscript in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a little javascript file that I need to run before my site loads (it contains some modernizr code and some more). 
Usually I add it using `includeJS` but for performance issues I need it inline. As workaround I am including it using `headerData` in this way:

```
headerData {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value (
        <script>
           // Here goes my javascript code
        <script>
    )
}
```

It works but it is ugly and difficult to update. Is there a way to say something like

```
headerData {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value < include(../path/to/my/file.js)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how this is an performance improvement over `page.includeJs` but you can just render a template here:

```
headerData {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10.file = EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Templates/MyTemplate
}
```

Comment: Thanks it just needed `10.stdWrap.wrap = <script>|</script>` to work. And about the performance it is about the server response for extra files (in this case this js)

Comment: YW. Should work with the tags in the template as well.